# is it possible to hack a module by mymodule?

Tags: 7

A few times i had (sadly and not proper) to hack a module, like changing some functions or default images, is it possible to hack a module in a proper way by "mymodule", in order to override simple things like changeing the returns of htlm or css with something like

```
mymodulefunction_moduleoriginalfunction(%args)
```

and make sure "mymodule" overrides my code running after original module?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible in the manner you are describing. However, Drupal provides many _alter() hooks that allow various things to be altered as necessary, so that you don't have to hack anything.

However, without specifics on what you want to do, I cannot suggest any specific methods.

Answer (score 0):

Every module provides hook api, you can simply use that or create and apply patch as per your needs.
Its a bad practice to hack or change the code in any core/contrib module.